# Emacs 28.2 VC-git crashes on Mac Studio Ventura

Tags: vc, vc-mode

I migrated from a trashcan Intel MacPro running macOS Monterey to a MacStudio running Ventura.

I installed Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/, version 28.2. On the Intel MacPro I am using Emacs 26.3.

VC-git is running just fine on Emacs 26.3, both on Intel and AARM. On Emacs 28.2 it appears it's running into some sort of recursive loop, creating a lot of garbage that needs to be collected. After some time, it crashes.

I gave Full Disk Access to Emacs.app in System Settings, and Emacs is able to open files with no problem.

Any thoughts on what's going on? For the time being I'll stick with Emacs 26.3.

Here's a crash report.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Emacs-arm64-12 [48805]
Path:                  /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-arm64-12
Identifier:            Emacs-arm64-12
Version:               ???
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-06-21 15:16:47.6564 -0700
OS Version:            macOS 13.4 (22F2073)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5A138F20-889D-DB8B-399E-E661B49260B6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       02AECF4E-A0D7-415D-BDBD-9B01158E85FE

Time Awake Since Boot: 150000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       26014 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016e8cffb0
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x000000016e8cffb0

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [48805]

VM Region Info: 0x16e8cffb0 is in 0x16b260000-0x16e8d0000;  bytes after start: 57081776  bytes before end: 79
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)    167800000-168000000    [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
      GAP OF 0x3260000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD                 16b260000-16e8d0000    [ 54.4M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                       16e8d0000-16ea64000    [ 1616K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cad294 mark_object + 0
1   Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
2   Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
3   Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
[continues on...]
506 Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
507 Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
508 Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
509 Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440
510 Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100cadc1c mark_object + 2440

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x192bfeff0 __select + 8
1   Emacs-arm64-12                         0x100d4b2f4 -[EmacsApp fd_handler:] + 244
2   Foundation                             0x193c8354c __NSThread__start__ + 716
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192c33fa8 _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192c2eda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x192bf3f14 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x192c06240 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x192bfcb78 mach_msg_overwrite + 604
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x192bf4290 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x192d127e4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x192d110c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x192d104b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   AppKit                                 0x19605c334 _NSEventThread + 172
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192c33fa8 _pthread_start + 148
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192c2eda0 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x192c2ed8c start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000122088505   x1: 0x0000000000000019   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000192a594f4
    x4: 0x00000000177c0de7   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x000000000000002f   x7: 0x000000016f25bd38
    x8: 0x0000000000000004   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x00000000000000b7  x11: 0x0000000100d83b70
   x12: 0x0000000000000103  x13: 0x000000000000000c  x14: 0x0000000000100000  x15: 0x00000001011aa000
   x16: 0x000000000000c752  x17: 0x000000000000c752  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000122088610
   x20: 0x0000000000000004  x21: 0x0000000000000004  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x00000001011c8f38
   x24: 0x000000000037f2eb  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000100dd74a8  x27: 0x00000001011c3f10
   x28: 0x00000001011a9000   fp: 0x000000016e8d0060   lr: 0x0000000100cadc1c
    sp: 0x000000016e8d0010   pc: 0x0000000100cad294 cpsr: 0x20001000
   far: 0x000000016e8cffb0  esr: 0x92000047 (Data Abort) byte write Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x100ba0000 -        0x100db7fff Emacs-arm64-12 (*) <e9c7c685-1ecf-3f9e-a7c3-6664fd39d841> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-arm64-12
       0x101524000 -        0x101677fff libgnutls.30.dylib (*) <65edcf7b-929d-375f-a526-09912675bfe7> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libgnutls.30.dylib
       0x101354000 -        0x10135ffff libjansson.4.dylib (*) <18be0886-ee42-3d52-9c34-e7bee5397ec3> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libjansson.4.dylib
       0x1013ec000 -        0x101447fff libgmp.10.dylib (*) <30f901d6-8f8e-3f0e-b864-1b4cf8668b32> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libgmp.10.dylib
       0x101374000 -        0x10137ffff libintl.8.dylib (*) <233c4c12-e3d0-37f5-ae58-af0d2ba9e127> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libintl.8.dylib
       0x1014c4000 -        0x1014f7fff libnettle.8.dylib (*) <b2d53a81-fc41-3e42-93e4-d676717034ad> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libnettle.8.dylib
       0x101714000 -        0x10174bfff libhogweed.6.dylib (*) <a68a51bf-72a1-34b0-883d-3a56c41eb07f> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/lib-arm64-12/libhogweed.6.dylib
       0x1076ec000 -        0x1076f7fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib (*) <570c31f7-94c6-3b86-ae44-1694db0a4bcd> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x192bf3000 -        0x192c2cfe7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <42f503e2-9273-360a-a086-c1b19bbd3962> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x193c2d000 -        0x1945f2fff com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <c96de80b-5c6c-3ef0-b25e-921448fb35bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
       0x192c2d000 -        0x192c39fff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <46d35233-a051-3f4f-bba4-ba56dddc4d1a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x192c93000 -        0x19316cfff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <203e4401-8c2e-3157-a24b-92f52551d43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x195ef9000 -        0x196e07fff com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <a7ed006c-dc81-3026-b80f-2676604e45eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.0G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.0G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=3.5G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=3.5G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               128K        1 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 1536K        4 
CG image                           176K        8 
ColorSync                          544K       28 
CoreAnimation                     2560K        9 
CoreGraphics                        48K        3 
CoreUI image data                  720K       10 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Image IO                           320K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           685.5M      134 
MALLOC guard page                  192K        8 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)           2.4G       21         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       54.5M        4 
Stack                             11.2M        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                        176K       11 
__AUTH                             682K      179 
__AUTH_CONST                      13.3M      346 
__CTF                               824        1 
__DATA                            7297K      335 
__DATA_CONST                      15.4M      354 
__DATA_DIRTY                       708K      110 
__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 
__LINKEDIT                       804.0M        9 
__OBJC_RO                         66.3M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2011K        1 
__TEXT                           250.2M      369 
dyld private memory                272K        2 
mapped file                      201.8M       28 
shared memory                      880K       16 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              4.9G     2003 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.1G     2003
```

Comment: whittle your config down to vc-git and only vc-git. if still have a problem and think you've found a bug report it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Do try to come up with a minimal recipe as @nega says (it will help people to attempt to reproduce the issue); but as this is an actual crash, please `M-x report-emacs-bug` *regardless* of whether you can narrow it down.  (Emacs shouldn't crash, so any case of that ought to be reported.)

Comment: indeed! what @phils said. that crash is very worthy of `M-x report-emacs-bug` regardless of your config. i can't remember the last time i've seen Emacs SIGSEGV on me, and i've never had a hard crash like that on macos/osx

Comment: @ovidiu: where did you get the command ```Emacs-arm64-12```? When using this version I started with ```Emacs-arm64-11``` on M1 machine.

Comment: @Ian I opened Emacs.app from Finder. But you're right, I could not find `Emacs-arm64-12` anywhere inside the /Applications/Emacs.app directory, I don't know how this comes up.

Comment: @Ian It turns out the stack above was from the Emacs 27.2 version, which does have a `Emacs-arm64-12` binary inside it.

Comment: Emacsformacosx is a universal application, contains both Intel and M1 versions, so the command you use may be for Intel. That one specified in my previous comment is for M1 and was used to launch the GUI application from terminal. I had also some problems with version 28.2, freezing at startup but not crashing, so I moved to nightly version, without problems - you can try also pre-release version 29 instead. I do not know your goals with Emacs, but you can try also https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus, which will be compiled from sources on your computer.

Comment: @Ian It looks like VC-git under Emacs 28.2 works just fine listing the changes in a directory (C-x v d) except in one of the repositories that's causing the crash. The VC-git version that's been packaged with Emacs 26.3 has no such issue. I'll stick with 26.3 for now until I find some time to look at what's going on, even though it runs under Rosetta emulation.

Comment: @Ian Just to confirm that the problem is vc-git, I replaced the `Contents/Resources/lisp/vc/vc-git.el.gz` file in Emacs 28.2 with the file in 26.3. Everything works as expected, including in the repository where it was previously crashing. The next step is identifying the change(s) that cause the crash.